# while progress bar is running how to disable other controls of the page in WPF

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can i have a loading/progress bar on the page while it is taking time to call a service,also until the call and response is not complete the controls should not be accessible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way, Create a empty grid behind the Progress Bar that cover the whole screen and set its opacity of say 0.5 so that background is paritially visible.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="GrdProgressBar"  Background="Transparent"  >
        <Grid Background="White" Opacity="0.5"></Grid>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Foreground="Green" Margin="0,5,0,0" ></ProgressBar>
            <TextBlock Text="loading.." FontSize="20"  FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Black"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
```

What you have to done set the visibility of `GrdProgressBara as you do with ProgessBar.

Hope it help you :)

Comment: @loop Still user can click on background controls like textbox, button etc. I want those controls not active while service is loading data.

Comment: @waghekapil make sure your "GrdProgressBar" taking whole screen.. in that case it won't..

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use a property `IsLoading` that is true while the service call is in progress and false after the call finished. Then you can use a converter and bind your `IsEnabled` property of your controls to the inverse `IsLoading` value. So while your service call is running, all controls are disabled and when the call finishes, the control will be reenabled. You just need to set the `IsLoading` property and bind within XAML. No additional code needed.

Comment: I was doing the same using code instead of binding by storing an instance of my current progressbar and switching its visibility. This is a much better way, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @xmashallax Can you please provide some example?